# unable to get 3 python scripts running on crontab and rc.local

Tags: python, cron

I'm facing a problem of getting my `rc local` to work when I boot up and nothing seems to work. How can I get 3 of my python scripts running when I boot up?

I tried `crontab` but I can't work out how to get it to function with 3 python scripts. I've tried the following steps and on `crontab` I just use @reboot `tempstream.py`.

```
sleep1
python /home/pi/tempstream.py &
python /home/pi/streamheart.py &
python /home/pi/gps.py &
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify the absolute path to python for this to work.

so **/usr/bin/python** instead of just **python**

but personally I think its more pretty and shorter if you add 
`#!/usr/bin/python`  to the first line of  each of your python files
and then chmod +x each .py file to make it executable.

then you can have:

```
sleep 1
/home/pi/tempstream.py &
/home/pi/streamheart.py &
/home/pi/gps.py &
```

Also in your example you have a typo for the sleep command  the **1**  should be separated by a space from sleep.

Another idea would be to actually make a a real service of this with a systemd unit file. Its easier than you think.

Comment: where should i add the chmod +x at the py file? do i just type at the terminal $ chmod +x tempstream.py or what?